# Pagination of text in GUI

Tags: java, swing, text, pagination, jtextcomponent

I write book reader using Java Swing.  Is it possible to paginate some text in a panel?  In what way I can do **pagination**?

Comment: *"tnx"*  Please don't use silly, made up words.  As to your question, why would I as a user want pagination when I can have scroll?  All these 'PDF like' paginated viewers confound me.  To get a readable size for portrait mode text, the page length needs to be taller that screen size, so we are still forced to scroll up/down, then with the added complication of using different controls to navigate to the next/previous part.  Yuck!  Do your users a favor and add the text component to a `JScrollPane` - the user can 'paginate it' by hitting the `page down` key, or clicking the scroll-bar.

Answer (score 3):

http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html

Or you can use http://java-sl.com/JEditorPanePrinter.html to preview and print content